# FirebaseOptions Exceptioon

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

whenever i run my code am getting this Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
```

Even though am not using firebase any where in my app.
Yeah, tried with few solutions from similar questions. But nothing didnt work.

Here is my bild.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
compile files('libs/main .jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: post you build.gradle file content please

Comment: Posted build dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is the new version of Google Cloud Messaging platform. From your gradle it seems that you have added all the play-services and hence firebase is also added to your project. Try replacing

```
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

with only those dependencies that you need in your project. You can refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more information.

Comment: Tried using 9.0.0 version. Getting the same problem.

Comment: You removed the whole play-services dependency and added only those you need right?

Comment: i included this
"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0"

Comment: Replace it with separate dependencies for only those libraries that you need in your project. You can get the separate dependencies from the link i provided.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yup its working now after replacing with separate dependency. Thanks.

Comment: @GeethakrishnaJuluri glad to be of help. Can you then please accept my answer?